# Ajax POST function returning the same result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just encountered a problem trying to populate two dropdown selection menus using jQuery, Ajax and php. The code keeps loading the same value from database even if a different option is selected from the dropdown menu. Here is a snippet of the code

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="self.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div><label><strong>class:</strong></label></div></td>
                <td><div><select name="class_id" id="class_id_0">
                        <option value="" selected>Select a Class</option>
                        <option value="1">Nursery</option>
                        <option value="2">Primary</option>
                        <option value="3">Secondary</option>
                        </select></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><label><strong>Sub-Class:</strong></label></div></td>
                <td><div><select name="sub_class_id" id="sub_class_id_0">
                            <option value="">Select a Sub - Class</option>
                        </select></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><label><strong>Subject:</strong></label></div></td>
                <td><div><select name="subject_id" id="subject_id_0">
                            <option value="">Select a Subject</option>
                        </select></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
(function($){
    $("#class_id_0").change(function(){
        var str = "";
        var type = "sub_class";
        $( "#class_id_0 option:selected" ).each(function() {
            str += $( this ).val() + " ";
        });
        $.post( "data.php",{class_id:parseInt(str),type:""+type}).done(function(data){
                            alert(str);
                            alert( "Data Loaded:" + data );
                            $("#sub_class_id_0").html(data); 
        });
    });
    $("#sub_class_id_0").change(function(){
        var str = "";
        var type = "subject";
        $( "#sub_class_id_0 option:selected" ).each(function() {
            str += $( this ).val() + " ";
        });
        $.post( "data.php",{sub_class_id:parseInt(str),type:""+type}).done(function(data){
                            alert(str);
                            alert( "Data Loaded:" + data );
                            $("#subject_id_0").html(data); 
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
    $options = "";
    $query = "";
    $type = isset($_REQUEST["type"]);
    switch($type){
            case "sub_class": 
                $sub_class_id = intval($_REQUEST["sub_class_id"]);
                $default_value = "";
                $default_text = "Select a Sub - Class";
                    $options = "<option value='".$default_value."'>".$default_text."</option>";
                    if($class_id == "" || $class_id == 0)
                    {
                            $options = "<option value = >Select a Class First</option>";
                    }

                    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
                    $database = mysql_select_db('admin_glisten');
                    $sql="SELECT sub_class_id,sub_class FROM sub_class WHERE class_id = '".$class_id."'"; 
                    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
                    if (!$result) {
                            die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
                    }
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $options .= "<option value='".$row['sub_class_id']."'>".$row['sub_class']."</option>";
                    }
                    echo $options;
                    mysql_close($con); 
                break;
            case "subject":
            $sub_class_id = intval($_REQUEST["sub_class_id"]);
            $default_value = "";
                $default_text = "Select a Subject";
                    $options = "<option value='".$default_value."'>".$default_text."</option>"; 
            if($sub_class_id  == "" || $sub_class_id  == 0)
                    {
                            $options = "<option value = >Select a Sub - Class First</option>";
                    }

                    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
                    $database = mysql_select_db('admin_glisten');
                    $sql="SELECT subject_scheduler.subject_id,subject.subject_id,subject.name FROM subject_scheduler INNER JOIN subject ON subject_scheduler.subject_id=subject.subject_id  WHERE sub_class_id = '".$sub_class_id."'"; 
                    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
                    if (!$result) {
                            die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
                    }
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $options .= "<option value='".$row['subject_id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
                    }
                    echo $options;
                    mysql_close($con);  
                break;
            default:
    }

?>
```

**PS**
Never mind my insecure code am just trying to get it to work. Any help will be gratefully appreciated, as i have been on this for the past couple of hours now.

Comment: If your `$class_id` and `$sub_class_id` are to be integers -> `$class_id = intval(...)`/`$sub_class_id = intval(...);` why are you building them as a string in your jquery -> `var str = ""; str += $( this ).val() + " "; class_id: ""+str`?

Comment: I have made the the change, but I am still getting the same error. The result from the top levelselect sub-class dropdown menu keeps populating the subject dropdown menu,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using $class_id variable to query the database, but $class_id is always going to be the same. Here is why:

On line 4 of PHP code

```
$class_id = intval(isset($_REQUEST["class_id"]));
```

Intval returns an integer, which is fine, however, you are also calling isset, which returns a boolean. In most cases isset results in true and then intval results in 1.

So in fact your query is always:

```
SELECT sub_class_id,sub_class FROM sub_class WHERE class_id = '1';
```

Comment: but if i remove isset(); function, I keep getting the following error: Unidentified index: sub_class_id in "C:\xampp\htdocs\data.php"

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the assignment in the if clause, e.g. `if (isset($_REQUEST["class_id"])) { $class_id = intval($_REQUEST["class_id"]); } else { $class_id = "some default value"; } `?

Comment: @user28864 You are not sending `sub_class_id` in your ajax -> `$.post( "data.php",{class_id: ""+str,type:""+type})`. You are only sending `class_id` and `type`, so `sub_class_id` will always be undefined.

Comment: I have figured that out, by moving the $sub_class_id to the switch case : "subject". But now the result from the top level sub-class menu keeps populating the the Subject dropdown menu. Any ideas? By the way thanks so much for all the suggestions. I really appreciate it

Comment: Thanks guys, I just saw my huge mistake, it was a semantic error...cheers